# A file viewer like in Total Commander / Krusader

Tags: software-recommendation, preview, development, logs, text-editor

I use DoubleCommander, which is a decent 2-panel file manager.
What I am missing is a viewer for the use case of peeking at a text file, especially logs:

- quick to load
- handles large text files (GBs)
- handles page up/down
- allows find / next / previous / highlight

  - remembers the searched strings
- zoom, ideally with Control + mouse wheel
- capable of closing with "esc"
- capable of reloading the file *on demand* (F5)

  - remembers the position over reloads
- ideally, configurable key shortcuts
  etc.

In short, something to quickly open the file, find a string, have it open, reload when necessary at roughly the same place. Developers will find this very familiar.

Is there such app? Sublime it aint, File Viewer neither, jEdit neither, TextEdit neither... I've tried quite a lot of them but there's always some blocker.

Both Krusader and Total Commander have great viewers, so I believe Mac community produced one, too. (Not counting running Total Commander in Wine :)

Comment: So why isn't something like Sublime text good? Maybe it has something to do with how it seems you want this app to be some sort of combination of a file manager and a text editor. Like I don't understand why you would need to refresh a text file in a text editor. I do understand why you would want to do it in a file manager.

Comment: See Commander One from Eltima, it is approved by C.Ghisler as Total Commander for Mac.

Comment: @Joonas I do not need a text editor. I need a text viewer. It doesn't really matter whether you open it from a manager or Finder or a console. Sublime is not appropriate because it can't handle large files, that alone is a blocker.

Comment: [Ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) will probably work on a Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the closest match is [DoubleCommander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/). With some Mac quirks, as Mac lacks keys like Insert, PgUp/PgDn so it's impossible to map the actions to shortcuts I am used to. But still, it's a decent (cross-platform) two-panel manager.

Answer (score -1):

The **Console.app** is quite close. Except it doesn't support zooming and even I can't manage to set the font size. Not sure how that works on Apple, there's the font dialog but that doesn't change the text size.